# Is there a better way to use the operator to select a group in an expression in Select by Attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

Is there a better method to do a group like in a row or in colum that you want to select from in using the Select by Attribute?  I have a point shapefile that I have has photo index. The field has all the numbers that looks like this 32-50,32-51,32-52, so on. This field Photo is in string/text data type.

I have a trouble using the expression but this one is the only way I can do

> "PHOTO" IN ( '11-94', '11-95', '11-96', '11-97', '11-98', '11-99',
>   '11-100', '11-101', '11-102')

Here is the screenshot I have here [image]

Comment: LIKE '11-\*' or LIKE '11-%' depending on your data type.. personal GDB is asterisk, file GDB and shapefile is percent. This will select anything that starts with '11-'. Read more about LIKE (not facebook like) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql and more about Esri SQL http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=SQL_reference

Comment: This is one of the most inefficient queries (except, I guess, `NOT IN (...)`), since it translates to *N* `column = value` queries. You had best have an index on the searched column. Creating a lookup table of just keys will scale better, since you can subselect (`WHERE column IN (SELECT column FROM jointable)`) or just join (`WHERE joincol IS NOT NULL`)

Comment: Ah yes @Vince if you quantify efficiency by search speed, if you however quantify efficiency by amount of typing and clicking skipped it is indeed more efficient... if the query takes 10 more seconds to execute but saves 10 minutes of typing I see that as efficiency. Not all feature types support extended queries, notably shapefiles and file geodatabase feature classes so your extended query, while correct for enterprise/personal databases, is not suited to all feature types.

Comment: I like the LIKE query mentioned by @Michael Stimson.  Alternatively,  it looks like the PHOTO attribute is a combination of ROLL and FRAME (in most cases)...perhaps something like `"ROLL" = 11 and "FRAME" >=94 and "FRAME" <= 102` would be more efficient?

Comment: Thanks that worked...but I use this method  "ROLL">= 32 AND "FRAME" <=  43 AND "ROLL" = 32 AND "FRAME" >=  35